Avalonia Unable to cast object exception
I have created what amounts to a single-page application with Avalonia. In this application, the layout is like this:

As shown in the img, on the left is NavigationView, and on the right is the Frame Control. I would like to use Frame Control to display those two pages(home , tools).
Code looks like this:
<ui:NavigationView 
    PaneDisplayMode="Left" 
    IsBackButtonVisible="False"
    IsSettingsVisible="False"
    IsPaneToggleButtonVisible="False"
    Width="80"
    ItemInvoked="NavView_OnItemInvoked"
    Name = "NavView">
        
<ui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <ui:NavigationViewItem 
        Content="Home" 
        Tag="Home"
        SelectsOnInvoked="True">     
    </ui:NavigationViewItem>
    <ui:NavigationViewItem 
        Content="tools" 
        Tag="Tools"
        SelectsOnInvoked="True">
    </ui:NavigationViewItem>
</ui:NavigationView.MenuItems>
        
<ui:Frame Name="Frame"></ui:Frame>
</ui:NavigationView>

<ContentControl 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Margin="10,10,0,0"  
    CornerRadius="50">
    <ui:Frame 
        Name="Frame2" 
        Navigated="Frame2_OnNavigated">    
    </ui:Frame>
</ContentControl>`


I also do something on the subpage that displays the Frame Controls.
Such as HomePage(HomeView)， I have placed two controls in this view, one is TextBlock and the other is a Button.
I have Binding both of these two Controls
This is Code:
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <TextBlock Width="300" Background = "Red" Text="{Binding GTER, FallbackValue='null'}"></TextBlock>
    <Button Background = "Transparent" BorderBrush = "Transparent" Command="{Binding ButtonAction}">名字</Button>
</Grid>

When I execute it, A ERROR HAS BEEN THROWN!
ERROR LIKE THIS:
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'APP.ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel' to type 'APP.ViewModels.HomeViewModel
I have found a solution on GitHub Link
I followed his advice and modified my code:
<TextBlock Width="300" Background = "Red" Text="{Binding $parent.((vm:HomeViewModel)DataContext).GTER, FallbackValue='null'}"></TextBlock>
<Button Background = "Transparent" BorderBrush = "Transparent" Command="{Binding $parent.((vm:HomeViewModel)DataContext).ButtonAction">名字</Button>

BUT IT DID NOT WORK!
TextBlock always displays null instead of the Binding value.
The button also becomes unclickable.
Does anybody give me a clue as to what I am doing wrong?

I Figure it out!
Solution:
axmal =><Design.DataContext><vm:yourViewModel></Design.DataContenxt>
axmal.cs => yourView(){DataContext = new yourViewModel()}

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
